# How to centralise content within a drawer (material ui)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**I'm trying to achieve the following below:**

[image]

**What I'm getting**

[image]

I've attempted to Grids to align centrally, but the grid does not seem to do the trick. What else material UI components can I use.

```
export default function NoneSelectedPage(props) {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      alignItems="center"
      justifyItems="center"
      direction="column"
      spacing={1}
    >
      <Grid item>
        <PetsIcon fontSize="large"></PetsIcon>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography>Nothing selected.</Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: set the Grid height as same as the parent of Grid.

Comment: The parent is a box.  <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}> 
What height do I set the Grid as @kyun